# Making non responsive HTML reduce correctly for full-screen display in mobile devices

Tags: css

I've built flat page sites for years, largely with table architecture, and I know they must become more mobile compatible.

However, I actually WANT some of my non responsive sites to display in mobile screens as simply reduced-sized versions of themselves.

In an effort to understand the basics, I've created a simple page, no tables, one piece of art, and the meta tag  which I understand is supposed to reduce a large size HTML page to fit within a mobile screen. But when I check this in a mobile screen emulator, my page is huge with just part of itself showing in the mobile screen. It's not reducing so that its full contents show within the screen.

What's the basic concept I'm missing?

http://ldihealtheconomist.com/html5-test-single-col.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a set width.

No matter what screen you're using, if you set the width as pixels then it will be displayed as that many pixels.

No offense, but if you've been making sites for years and don't know this, then maybe it's not the right thing for you...

Read up on `@media` queries, `vw`,`vh` and viewport widths.

Look at frameworks such as Bootstrap or Skeleton.